# Purrr: Which nested dataframe encountered the error?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Here is a nested data.

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
   ~A,        ~B,  ~group,
   4L,         1L,  "A",
   7L,         4L,  "A",
  NA_integer_, 1L,  "B",
  NA_integer_, 10L, "B")

df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(group) %>% nest()
```

I need to run lm using purrr:map.

```
map(df2$data, ~lm(A~B, data=.x))
```

What's the best way to find out which nested data encountered an error i.e. how can I know that group B has an issue.

Can you suggest a solution may be using purrr's possibly or safely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `possibly()` here.  In my example I have it return `NA` if the model has an error.

First I make `posslm`, using `otherwise` to tell it what to return if there is an error after using `lm`.

```
posslm = possibly(lm, otherwise = NA)
```

Then you can make a new column of models with `map` in `mutate`.  Once that's done, `filter` to `NA` rows for the new variable and then pull out the `group`.

```
mutate(df2, mod = map(data, ~posslm(A~B, data=.x))) %>%
    filter( is.na(mod) ) %>%
    pull(group)

[1] "B"
```

Comment: How have I gone so long using R and never known about possibly? This is life-changing.